# retrieving user id of user from table row as cannot assing id using <a> tag to row

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

i have a user table and make each of its row link using jquery .I want to redirect user to his profile when the user clicks on a specific row by using user id as a key.how can I get the user_id from the table row while clicking on the row

the user will be redirected to the profile of the user he selects

Comment: Please provide your code

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in using laravel only.

```
<a href="{{ route('route-name',$user->userid) }}">{{ $user->username }}</a>
```

Comment: making table row a link cannot be done by this.....we have to use jquery for that....and that is what i am asking that how I can I access the link value assigned to eah row in jquery

Comment: @DaniyalIbrahim can you provide your code so I can try to help you out ?